# Echoing using field names with fetch_all() - php

Tags: php

I wondered if anyone can help.  I am fairly new to php and I am having a problem with some syntax.  I ave a PDO connection to an SQL database,  it works fine, but my issue is that I can only echo - out using the array address after having gathered the data using a fetch_all() statement.  Can I echo using the field names?  Here is the section of code that is causing an issue:

```
// connect to the database using the new more secure PDO method
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webauth', 'tim', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_cust WHERE pk_cust_id=$custid;";  //'$custid'
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$names = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<table border='2'> 
<tr>
<th>cust first</th>
<th>cust last</th>
</tr>";


  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $names[0][2] . "</td>"; //this displays the second field correctly
  echo "<td>" . $names['cust_firstname'] . "</td>"; //just ignores this command - no error     though
  echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
echo $names[0][2];  //this does work and shows the firstname
echo $names->cust_firstname;  //this doesnt work - doesnt crash, but shows nothing     cust_firstname is the SQL field
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare it as an associative array it should work

```
$names = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then the following should output

```
$names['cust_firstname']
```

Comment: Thank you guys, that explains a lot.  Does an associative array use the first row as an "index"?

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll` returns you an array with each element representing a row from your result organized like this:

```
[0] - First row
     array(
        'field1' => 'value',
        'field2' => 'value'
     )
     ...
[1] - Second row
     array(
        'field1' => 'value',
        'field2' => 'value'
     )
```

If you are sure that you only receive one row from your query you can access the value like this:

```
$names[0]['your_field_name'];
```